# npm ERR! Cannot find module 'spdx-expression-parse'

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, npm-install, node-modules

This error occurred while command npm run watch was in process, I tried to solve it with different tactics but can't find any solution

Steps which I tried to resolve the issue

1) Remove node module, package-lock.json, yarn.lock npm cache clear and the run npm install but error still occurs.

2) Remove nodejs from control panel and reinstall with latest and then old/previous version and the reinstall but can't succeed, error still occurs.

> npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND npm ERR! Cannot find module
>   'spdx-expression-parse'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-12-20T08_00_01_749Z-debug.log

Log File

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install' ]
2 info using npm@6.5.0
3 info using node@v8.12.0
4 verbose stack Error: Cannot find module 'spdx-expression-parse'
4 verbose stack     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
4 verbose stack     at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
4 verbose stack     at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
4 verbose stack     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
4 verbose stack     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\validate-npm-package-license\index.js:1:75)
4 verbose stack     at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
4 verbose stack     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
4 verbose stack     at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
4 verbose stack     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
4 verbose stack     at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
5 verbose cwd D:\it-88-lynx
6 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
7 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
8 verbose node v8.12.0
9 verbose npm  v6.5.0
10 error code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
11 error Cannot find module 'spdx-expression-parse'
12 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling `npm`?

Comment: @MatthewHerbst Yes i tried, but same error occured

Comment: is `spdx-expression-parse` listed as dependency in your `package.json`?

Comment: thanks @MatthewHerbst

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atlast, I have solved the problem, the spdx-expression-parse has been corrupted located in `users/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/`

```
remove node_modules
uninstall nodejs
```

(**Start Main Step**)

```
Go to users/AppData/Roaming and delete npm and npm-cache folders manually
```

(**End Main Step**)

then run following command

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json yarn.lock
npm cache clear --force
npm install
```

thanks for all your suppport.